# Windows 7 - Find all files that are alone in a folder

Tags: windows-7, find, file-search

I need to find a way to select all files that are alone in their folders, so I can cut and paste them someplace else. All respective folders are inside one main root folder. Is there a command prompt, or total commander trick for this?

Comment: What do you want to happen on subdirectories? Do you flag a sole file in a directory which also contains one or more subdirectories? Or a single subdirectory where there are no other files in its parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET ROOT_FOLDER=C:\TEST 1
SET TARGET_FOLDER=C:\TEST 2

FOR /D %%G IN ("%ROOT_FOLDER%"\*) do (
CD %%G
    FOR /f %%A in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do (
        set cnt=%%A
        Echo %%G  : !cnt!
        IF !cnt! == 1 (
            move /-y "*.*" "%TARGET_FOLDER%"
        )
    )
)
```

This Batch will look inside `C:\TEST 1` sub folders an count files. once it finds a lonely file it'll move it to `C:\TEST 2`. it will also ask for overwrite in case file name already exist.

Replace `C:\TEST 1` and `C:\TEST 2` with your own values.

you can add `pause` at end of the batch to read the files count echo'ed by it.

Answer (score 6):

```
$src = "G:\temp"
$target = "G:\notalone"

if (Test-Path $src)
{
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
        $fc = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Expand Count
        if ($fc -eq 1)
        {
            $file = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object
            Write-Host "Moving " $file.FullName " to " $target
            Move-Item $file.FullName $target
        }
    }
}
```

This should work in Powershell, replace src and target. If you have the same filenames, it will not overwrite. You can add force to Move-Item to make that happen.

This could probably be condensed, I'm novice with powershell.